# Vim - How to run a non normal mode command in all buffers?

Tags: regex, vim, vi, replace

I need to run this command `:perldo s/assigned_to(?!_member|_role)/assigned_to_member/g` in all open buffers. I'm using `:perldo` because the builtin vim regex (i.e. `%s/foo/bar/g`) isn't working with my negative lookahead for some reason.

Through my research I've found the `:bufdo` and `:execute "normal <foo>"` commands but I haven't yet figured out how to combine them.

Does anyone know how I would be able to run the perldo command on all my open buffers? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
:bufdo! perldo s/assigned_to(?!_member|_role)/assigned_to_member/g
```

Comment: That worked! What does the `!` after `:bufdo` do? That might have been what I was missing!

Comment: I'd recommend reading `:h bufdo!` in Vim. If you don't have the time (khm): if `perldo` fails (can't replace anything in any of the buffers) "normal" `:bufdo` "exits". With `!` the `perldo` command continues on the next buffer.

Comment: The exclamation mark either forces something (e.g. `wq!`) or acts as a toggle switch. But it depends on the command. In this case for `bufdo` if the buffer can't be abandoned then the command would fail.